# ¿Por que al recuperar datos de un archivo JSON no funciona con POST?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, json

Aprendiendo ajax me topo con que no funciona el llamado en html y la consola da el siguiente error

> XHR POST "archivo JSON" [HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed 1ms].

La consigna del problema era cambiar la peticion con GET a con POST. Siendo html el archivo no funciona, verifique el codigo y no encuentro errores. Cambien el archivo a php y funciono sin mas. Si alguien es tan amable de explicarme esto se lo agradeceria. Dejo el codigo por las dudas

**html:**

```
   function mostrarSugerencia(str) {
   var paisElegido='';
   if (str=='spain') {paisElegido='España';}
   else if (str=='mexico') {paisElegido='México';}
   else if (str=='argentina') {paisElegido='Argentina';}
   else if (str=='colombia') {paisElegido='Colombia';}
   else {paisElegido='none';}

   var xmlhttp;
   if (str.length==0 ||paisElegido=='none') { document.getElementById("txtInformacion").innerHTML="no hay datos";
   mostrarCiudades(); return; }
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
       var jsonResponse = xmlhttp.responseText;
       var objeto_json = JSON.parse(jsonResponse);
       paisesRecibidos = objeto_json.listadoPaises.pais;
       for (var i=0; i<paisesRecibidos.length;i++) {
       var nombrePais = objeto_json.listadoPaises.pais[i].nombre;
           if (nombrePais==paisElegido) {
           document.getElementById("txtInformacion").innerHTML = 'El pais recibido por get en segundo plano es '+nombrePais+ ' y tiene indice '+i;
           var ciudadesPais = objeto_json.listadoPaises.pais[i].ciudadImportante;
           mostrarCiudades(ciudadesPais);
           }
       }
       
   }
   }
   
   var cadenaParametros = 'pais='+encodeURIComponent(str);
   xmlhttp.open('POST', 'listadoPaises.json'); // Método post y url invocada
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); // Establecer cabeceras de petición
   xmlhttp.send(cadenaParametros); // Envio de parámetros usando POST

   }
   
   function mostrarCiudades (arrayCiudades) {
   var nodoMostrarResultados = document.getElementById('listaCiudades');
   if (!arrayCiudades) {nodoMostrarResultados.innerHTML = ''; return}
   var contenidosAMostrar = '';
   for (var i=0; i<arrayCiudades.length;i++) {
       contenidosAMostrar = contenidosAMostrar+'<div id="ciudades'+i+'">';
       contenidosAMostrar += '<a href="http://aprenderaprogramar.com">' + arrayCiudades[i]+ '</a></div>';
   }
   if (contenidosAMostrar) {nodoMostrarResultados.innerHTML = contenidosAMostrar;}
   }
   </script>
```

Comment: El servicio que intentas consumir te está diciendo que ese endpoint no permite peticiones POST.

Comment: un poco off-topic a tu pregunta, no veo el porqué usar `POST` en tu petición. `POST` es comúnmente utilizado para enviar muchos datos, para, por ejemplo, insertar datos en BD, mandar a llamar algún proceso... etc etc. viendo lo que estás haciendo, a mí me parece correcto usar `GET` en vez de `POST`.

Comment: Los errores 4xx son del cliente, https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:C%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP